# Adding a shortcut key to an html element using JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<li><a href="javascript:onUsersClick();" id="masterUsersMenu">Users</a>
```

How can I add a shortcut key combination to the above html element. Something like

```
<li><a href="javascript:onUsersClick();" id="masterUsersMenu" shortcut= "Ctrl+U">Users</a>
```

so that when "Ctrl+U" is pressed the method is called automatically.

Comment: Note that in some browsers, Google Chrome for example, `ctrl` + `u` is the keyboard short-cut for 'view source.' Try not to override expected browser behaviour, perhaps try `ctrl` + `shift` + `u` ([simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8s4tN/1/))

Answer (score 3):

use `accesskey`

for example :

```
<li><a href="javascript:onUsersClick();" id="masterUsersMenu" accesskey="PREFFERED_ACCESS_KEY">Users</a>
```

the way to trigger the access key depends on the browser you are using and the `accesskey` value you put in the element

for detailed info to use access keys refer [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Comment: So it will be `[Alt]` + `c`

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools, use [*MDN:accesskey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) for examples and [*HTML5 specification*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#using-the-accesskey-attribute-to-define-a-command-on-other-elements) for definitive guidance.

Comment: depends on the browser you are using. see the link on my post for details

Comment: +1, @ejay_francisco. What I meant was you could include that info in your answer because the Op is under the impression of `Ctrl`+`U` in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.accesskey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use jQuery. You may need to refer a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/sjNLs/

After all, if you need to use access key in a anchor you can see demo here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_accesskey

Remember `accesskey` works with `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JQuery

```
$(document).keypress("U",function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        onUsersClick();
    }
    return false
});
```

Comment: Just in case: `keypress` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) you should use `beforeinput` or `keydown` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A robust Javascript library for capturing keyboard input and key combinations entered. It has no dependencies.

https://jaywcjlove.github.io/hotkeys-js/

```
hotkeys('ctrl+a,ctrl+b,r,f', function(event,handler){
    switch(handler.key){
        case "ctrl+a":alert('you pressed ctrl+a!');break;
        case "ctrl+b":alert('you pressed ctrl+b!');break;
        case "r":alert('you pressed r!');break;
        case "f":alert('you pressed f!');break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct [link](https://wangchujiang.com/hotkeys-js/)